# Unable to Launch Sonar on windows VM

Tags: java, windows, elasticsearch, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

## I am installing sonar on Windows VM, when i tried executing sonar i got below error,
Environment

java 15.0.2 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing)
Sonar --sonarqube-8.7.0.41497

````
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2021.03.02 16:11:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory F:\sonarqube-8.7.0.41497\temp
2021.03.02 16:11:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on [HTTP: 127.0.0.1:9001, TCP: 127.0.0.1:62946]
2021.03.02 16:11:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [F:\sonarqube-8.7.0.41497\elasticsearch]: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-15.0.2\bin\java -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -Djava.io.tmpdir=F:\sonarqube-8.7.0.41497\temp -XX:ErrorFile=../logs/es_hs_err_pid%p.log -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60 -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10 -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -Xss1m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djna.nosys=true -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0 -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0 -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Xmx512m -Xms512m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Delasticsearch -Des.path.home=F:\sonarqube-8.7.0.41497\elasticsearch -Des.path.conf=F:\sonarqube-8.7.0.41497\temp\conf\es -cp lib/* org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch
2021.03.02 16:11:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
Unrecognized VM option 'UseConcMarkSweepGC'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
2021.03.02 16:11:43 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractManagedProcess] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2021.03.02 16:11:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[es] is stopped
2021.03.02 16:11:43 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
2021.03.02 16:11:44 ERROR app[][o.s.a.p.EsManagedProcess] Failed to check status
java.lang.RuntimeException: thread waiting for the response was interrupted
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1632)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1602)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1572)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.ClusterClient.health(ClusterClient.java:130)

    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler.refreshState(ManagedProcessHandler.java:220)
    at org.sonar.application.process.ManagedProcessHandler$EventWatcher.run(ManagedProcessHandler.java:285)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:321)
    at org.apache.http.concurrent.BasicFuture.get(BasicFuture.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:279)
    ... 11 common frames omitted
<-- Wrapper Stopped```
````

Answer (score 1):

Do not use Java 15. Apparently the switch that SonarQube uses has been [removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363). SonarQube only supports Java 11, as per [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/requirements/requirements/#header-3):

> SonarQube server requires version 11. Versions beyond Java 11 are not officially supported.

Comment: So i should install java 11 to get my sonarQube up and working